# IndexOutOfRangeException on Scripts.Render Bundle

Tags: bundles, indexoutofrangeexception

I have the following in my BundleConfig.cs file to set up two bundles that I am trying to render.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/knockout").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.debug.js",
                        "~/Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js",
                        "~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js",
                        "~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"));
```

Then I have this my shared layout to render the bundles, but I keep getting "IndexOutOfRangeException errors on these two lines:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
```

Answer (score 3):

It was a stupid mistake. Those were supposed to be `ScriptBundles` but I used `StyleBundles`.

It works now.

Comment: This stupid mistake I repeated.. :) 
You helped me :)